How does Quantum Gate Teleportation Actually Work?
I am trying to understand how quantum GATE teleportation works. Abstractly, I understand it as the ability to do a 2-qubit operation between two qubits that are not located in proximity.
From literature, the claim is that the way you do this is through a shared entangled state, and then a set of operations that look like regular teleportation (look at figure 2.a. here for reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2407.00835).
I have been trying to write down this protocol from the paper, but am having troubles manifesting this gate in the math.
The state is $|\psi\rangle_A\otimes | \phi_B \rangle \otimes |\Psi^+\rangle_{A'B'}$, where $|\psi\rangle_A$ is the state associated with Alice, $| \phi_B \rangle$ is associated with Bob and $|\Psi^+\rangle_{A'B'}$ is a shared entanglement qubit.
$$|\psi\rangle_A\otimes | \phi_B \rangle \otimes |\Psi^+\rangle_{A'B'} = (a|\uparrow\rangle_A + b|\downarrow\rangle_A)\otimes (c|\uparrow\rangle_B + d|\downarrow\rangle_B) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} + |\downarrow \rangle_{A'} | \uparrow\rangle_{B'}) $$
$$= (ac|\uparrow \rangle_A| \uparrow \rangle_B + ad |\uparrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B + bc |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B + bd |\downarrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} + |\downarrow \rangle_{A'} | \uparrow\rangle_{B'})$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(ac|\uparrow \rangle_A| \uparrow \rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} + ad |\uparrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} + bc |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} + bd |\downarrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} +
ac|\uparrow \rangle_A| \uparrow \rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\uparrow\rangle _{B'} + ad |\uparrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\uparrow\rangle _{B'} + bc |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\uparrow\rangle _{B'} + bd |\downarrow\rangle_A|\uparrow\rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'})$$
In the diagram, you will notice the application of a control Z operation between $A$ and $A'$ plus $B'$ and $B'$. When these are both down, the state gets a negative. The resulting state is
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(ac|\uparrow \rangle_A| \uparrow \rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} - ad |\uparrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} + bc |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} - bd |\downarrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B |\uparrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'} +
ac|\uparrow \rangle_A| \uparrow \rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\uparrow\rangle _{B'} + ad |\uparrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\uparrow\rangle _{B'} -bc |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\uparrow\rangle _{B'} - bd |\downarrow\rangle_A|\uparrow\rangle_B |\downarrow\rangle_{A'} |\downarrow\rangle _{B'})$$
Now the protocol modifies A' and B' (the entanglement link) with :
$$R_y(\pi/2)|\uparrow\rangle_{A'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow\rangle_{A'} + |\downarrow\rangle_{A'})$$
$$R_y(\pi/2)|\downarrow\rangle_{A'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (-|\uparrow\rangle_{A'} + |\downarrow\rangle_{A'})$$
$$R_x(\pi/2)|\uparrow\rangle_{B'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow\rangle_{B'} -i |\downarrow\rangle_{B'})$$
$$R_x(\pi/2)|\downarrow\rangle_{B'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (-i|\uparrow\rangle_{B'} + |\downarrow\rangle_{B'})$$
Substituting this into our state above and then factoring bell state terms will give some expression. For ease, let us assume it is the first bell basis where no other modification to the state is needed $|\Psi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow \uparrow \rangle + |\downarrow \downarrow\rangle)$. What am I suppose to expect as the final state? Should the algebra work out to be
$$(ac|\uparrow \rangle_A| \uparrow \rangle_B + ad |\uparrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B + bc |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B - bd |\downarrow\rangle_A|\downarrow\rangle_B)$$
(The original tensor of A and B ) but with $\downarrow \downarrow$ being negative now? Also, the algebra here gets very complicated, is there a more compact notation for this type of analysis?

If you can do regular quantum teleportation, it seems the straightforward way would be to just teleport those states you want to operate on to the gate's location, perform this gate operation, then teleport the output states back to their original locations?

Your question is ok here, but there's also a stack dedicated to QC:  https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

@James but is that effectively what the protocol is going on as described in the article? It seems that they are using some aspect of teleportation to effectively act as a control-Z operation on two qubits, not in local proximity...

@A.RadekMartinez it might be possible if particles A and B and the gate X is on Earth, particle C is on the moon, and particle D is on Mars, and A-C is entangled & B-D is entangled, then passing A, B through the gate will affect C and D too (the change must be communicated using light signal). I could not read through the up-down arrow notation you used though, perhaps using a more standard $|0100 \rangle$ notation will make the algebra easier to follow?
